# Overpaid Rent Owed By Real Estate

Tags: rental-property, australia, real-estate-leasing

Over the course of my last lease I had overpaid around 2 weeks rent to the real estate. I was notified of this when I moved out, but despite chasing them up about it they have failed to refund me the money.

I have called and emailed them so many times and they say "we'll do it shortly" but I moved out over a month ago now and nothing has been done.

The bond was refunded through the official channels but what do I do about the rest that needs to be refunded to me?

Comment: Do they have small claims courts in that mysterious country that you live in?

Comment: @littleadv I wasn't trying to be mysterious so I added a tag for clarity. Yes, it appears we have a small claims court.

Comment: Reading... http://www.lawlink.nsw.gov.au/Lawlink/lawaccess/ll_lawassist.nsf/pages/lawassist_debt_small_claims_home

Comment: I have the same question, but in London, UK... should I ask a separate question? or does someone know the equivalent body?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried complaining to the Real Estate Institute in your state, and if that doesn't work try taking them to Fair Trading.

I know from doing some work for real estates that getting money from them is like getting blood from a stone, but you just need to keep bugging them, talk to the manager or director, and tell them you have been waiting too long for your money, give them a deadline (not more than 3 business days) and tell them if you have not received the money by then you will make a complaint to the Real Estate Institute and take them to Fair Trading.

Sometimes you have to go to the person who owns/ runs the business as the workers usually don't care, especially when it is extra work for them and they get no reward for doing it (plus the longer the Real Estate don't pay you the longer they earn interest on your money).